# Snapshot of Dalvik Virtual Machine state

Tags: android, dalvik

I would like to know if it is possible to create a snapshot of the Dalvik Virtual Machine state? I would like to access the state of the variables of a method while executing an Android app in a real device.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ummm... use a breakpoint.

Comment: I think you mean "snapshot" rather than "screenshot".  If for some reason a debugger won't do what you need, you will need to provide more details about what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!What I mean is not debugging during development. I refer to, for example imagine an app running in a device, when an exception happens, I would like to access the value of all variables at the time of failure. Just like if it there is a breakpoint there during debugging. I would like to know if there is some way to access such kind of information at runtime.